# MBP M1 using HDMI output locks AVR to multi-channel PCM regardless of input source

Tags: audio, hdmi, midi

I’m having a sound/MIDI issue between my MBP M1 and my Pioneer VSX-LX503 AVR. When outputting sound using a MFi approved Belkin Thunderbolt 3 adaptor to HDMI, my receiver locks the input as multi-channel PCM.

No matter what app, sound or source i.e. Apple Music, Infuse player, Audirvana, etc outputting 5.1, 2.0, or Atmos it will always stay on 5.1 PCM.

I have a 5.1.4 Atmos set up,  so I set sound output to the AVR as Atmos always on, the MIDI is set to 8 channel 24 bit and then the speakers are set up as Atmos 5.1.2. When I run test sounds the speakers are accurate except channels 7 & 8 which should be Atmos sound coms out of my left and right rear surround the same as channels 5 & 6.

So I’m short, if I listen to a song that’s 2 channel the AVR is locked to 5.1 channel surround. DD+, DTS, Atmos or any surround do not register as anything but 5.1 multichannel PCM.

My Apple TV works just fine with the receiver and Pioneer says it’s a set up issue with MIDI. Can anyone please help?

Comment: I can't figure what Midi has to do with any of this, nor how it could possibly be set to 8 channel, 24-bit… Midi isn't an audio format at all, it's a data control structure. It stands for Musical Instrument Digital Interface. A data protocol, not an audio protocol.

Comment: See if the Audio MIDI Setup app can help you suss out the problem. Its a long-shot.

Comment: See the posting by BoogKnight at [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AppleMusic/comments/svja8t/dolby_atmos_via_hdmi_on_macbook_pro/) _"On your MacBook (with HDMI plugged into the receiver) go to the Audio MIDI Settings [sic] ... on your MacBook and make sure the output is set to HDMI and the correct number of speaker channels."_

Comment: MIDI has nothing to do with this, so forget that. I can't imagine why it would even be discussed in context of a receiver.

I have the VSX-LX305 and would be interested in whether you tried IconDaemon's advice and whether it worked.